# Warning: require_once and Fatal error: require_once(): when hosting the website

Tags: php, hosting, web-hosting

I upload my code in 000webhosting to publish the website but it shows an error. But no error in localhost. I hope you guys can help me because I'm new to the web developemnt.

The error:

> Warning: require_once(/storage/ssd1/726/17342726/public_html//RECYCLE
> AND REWARDING/include/config.php): failed to open stream: No such file
> or directory in
> /storage/ssd1/726/17342726/public_html/include/initialize.php on line
> 15
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
> '/storage/ssd1/726/17342726/public_html//RECYCLE AND
> REWARDING/include/config.php'
> (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in
> /storage/ssd1/726/17342726/public_html/include/initialize.php on line
> 15

link: https://recycle-and-rewarding-app.000webhostapp.com/

Below is my code on initialize.php

```html
<?php
//define the core paths
//Define them as absolute peths to make sure that require_once works as expected

//DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR is a PHP Pre-defined constants:
//(\ for windows, / for Unix)

defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null : define ('SITE_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].DS.DS.'RECYCLE AND REWARDING');

defined('LIB_PATH') ? null : define ('LIB_PATH',SITE_ROOT.DS.'include');

//load the database configuration first.
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS."config.php");
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS."function.php");
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS."session.php");
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS."accounts.php");
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS."autonumbers.php");  
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS."companies.php");  
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS."job.php");  
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS."employees.php");  
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS."categories.php");  
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS."applicant.php");  
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS."jobregistration.php");  
  
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS."database.php");
?>
```

Comment: This error is telling you that the web server can't find your files (initialize.php). It gives you the path that it is trying to find. You just need to check if the path in the web server is right. The given path is: `/storage/ssd1/726/17342726/public_html//RECYCLE AND REWARDING/include/config.php` Your files are in a folder called RECYCLE AND REWARDING? If not, that's your error. You need to point to correct path

Comment: Oh ya, I finally fix it based on your solution. Thank you